# How to correctly using order by with left join after group by

Tags: mysql

I have table name messages with columns as following

```
 1. id
 2. from_user
 3. to_user
 4. message
```

I want list the from_user as group by. The first entry should be whom who sent the last message. I am using following query

```
 SELECT
                     messages.*, signup.*
                     FROM messages
                     LEFT JOIN signup
                     ON messages.from_user = signup.id
                     WHERE messages.to_user = '$myUserid'
                     GROUP BY messages.from_user
                     ORDER BY messages.id DESC
```

I am joining other 'signup' table to grab the name of the user

```
    1.id
    2.name
```

unfortunately ORDER BY messages.id DESC doesnt ordering well. it is not returning the from_user on top who sent last message. Any suggestion?

SQL FIDDLE 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c70c3/1/0

Comment: can you please state some content into tables, so that there be a brief idea about it.

Comment: @danny If you could provide a SQL Fiddle, it would greatly help us answer your question. We have no idea what kind of data you have in your tables.

Comment: Maybe wrap it in a subquery?  SELECT * FROM (SELECT
                     messages.*, signup.*
                     FROM messages
                     LEFT JOIN signup
                     ON messages.from_user = signup.id
                     WHERE messages.to_user = '$myUserid'
                     GROUP BY messages.from_user) result order by result.id DESC

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1c70c3/1/0 is the sql fiddle. If we look in the table message the last message comes from from_user 8. So messages.id desc should come 8 first but its in the last